# How to play animation Third Person Controller of Starter Asset?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to move the character by mouse click, the player is moving but its animation is not working.
or Can anyone please configure whether my code is good or not

```cs
  if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
                RaycastHit hit;

                if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
                {
                    // Check if the raycast hit a walkable surface
                    if (hit.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
                    {
                        // Set the target position and start moving
                        target.transform.position = hit.point;
                        targetPosition = hit.point;
                        isMoving = true;
                    }
                }
            }


            if (isMoving)
            {
                MoveToPosition(targetPosition);
            }
```

```cs
  private void MoveToPosition(Vector3 targetPosition)
        {
            // Calculate the direction to the target position
            Vector3 direction = targetPosition - transform.position;
            direction.y = 0f; // Ignore vertical component

            // Rotate the character to face the target position
            if (direction.magnitude > 0.1f)
            {
                Quaternion toRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, toRotation, RotationSmoothTime * Time.deltaTime);
            }
            else
            {
                // Stop moving when the target position is reached
                isMoving = false;
                // Trigger the idle animation
                //_animator.SetBool("IsMoving", false);
                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, 6f);
                return;
            }

            // Move the character towards the target position
            _controller.Move(direction.normalized * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            // Trigger the walk animation
                _animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, 6f);

        }
```

this is my code I am new to Unity so kindly can anyone check if I am wrong or something else?

Comment: just as a side note: in the case you want to stop you probably want `_animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, 0f);` instead ... doesn't explain of course why your animation shouldn't start at all ...

Comment: watch whats happening in the animator.. you should see why its working or not

Comment: _animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, 0f); i try this but i didnt know how why it is not playing the animation

Comment: if you have mouse to click movement of third person controller can you plz send me i am just stuck in it and i didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

One possible issue is that `_animator.SetFloat(_animIDSpeed, 6f);` will set the appropriate `float` value in the animator, but the animation state itself is not activated.

In the character's animator tab, check the transition condition, for example (from Idle to Run):
[image]

The inspector will show you the conditions for the `Run` state to be activated.

[image]

Here, "isRunning" animator bool has to be `true` for the transition to happen. Hence, in the code I will write `_animator.SetFloat("isRunning", true);`